# Cで、b=a^aを満たすaが存在するか調べるコードを書いたところ、実行エラーになります

Tags: c

AtCoder Beginners Contest (ABC) 327-B を解くための問題をCで書きました。
問題は、「与えられた整数bについて、b=a^a を満たす整数aが存在するか」というものです。
bの最大値は制約により10^18です。
まず、aを1から初めて順にインクリメントし、aとa^aの表を作り、この表にbが含まれているかを調べています。
以下のコードは、Paiza.IOで小さな数で試したところうまく動いたのですが、AtCoderで提出してみると全て
RE(実行エラー)になりました。

```
typedef struct {
    long long n;
    long long n2;
} table;
long long readll(char *s);
long long ll_pow(long long x, long long n);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N1 21
#define N2 16
int main(void){
    char* s1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N1);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s1 failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(s1,N1,stdin);
    long long  b=readll(s1);
    free(s1);
    table* tb=(table*)malloc(sizeof(table)*N2);
    if(tb==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to tb failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<N2;j++){
        (tb+j)->n=0;
        (tb+j)->n2=0;
    }
    long long t1=1;
    long long t2=1;
    int i=0;
    while(1){
        t2=ll_pow(t1,t1);
        if (t2==0)break; 
        (tb+i)->n=t1;
        (tb+i)->n2=t2;
        t1+=1; i+=1;
    }
/*    for(int i=0;i<N2;i++){
        printf("%d :(%lld, %lld)\n",i+1,(tb+i)->n,(tb+i)->n2);
    }
*/
    int found=0;
    for(int j=0;j<N2;j++){
        if (b==(tb+j)->n2){
            found=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(tb);
    if(found==1){
        printf("Yes\n");
    }else{
        printf("No\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
long long readll(char *s){
    long long ret=0;
    int i=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
        ret*=10;
        ret+=*(s+i)-48;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
long long ll_pow(long long x, long long n){
    long long ret=1; 
    while(n>0){
        if(ret>1e18 || x>1e18){
            return 0;
        }
        if((n&1)==1)ret*=x;
        x*=x;
        n>>=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long longにて16^16を計算しようとしているのが原因です。

C言語では、符号付き整数のオーバーフローは未定義動作で、その結果何が起こるか分かりません。
long longの表現できる値の範囲は、-(2^63)から(2^63)-1までですが、16^16=(2^4)^16=2^64なので、オーバーフローして未定義動作となります。

`ll_pow`内の以下の判定でオーバーフロー対策をしているつもりかもしれませんが、`x`が4,294,967,296 (=2^32)の時にこちらの判定に引っ掛からないため、直後の`x*=x;`にて`x`が2^64となってしまい、オーバーフローしてしまいます。

```c
        if(ret>1e18 || x>1e18){
            return 0;
        }
        if((n&1)==1)ret*=x;
        x*=x;
```